# How to add a field to model with a decorator?

Tags: django, django-models, python-decorators

I'd like to add foreign keys to virtually every model in my app to allow different Sites. For this I think it would be nice to use decorators, because I will be able to only add those FKs under certain conditions (e.g. if Sites is installed).

Unfortunately my attempt doesn't do anything:

```
def add_site_fk_field(model_to_annotate: models.Model):
    """Add FK to Site to Model"""
    model_to_annotate.site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    return model_to_annotate

@add_site_fk_field
class Test(models.Model):
    ...
```

Is it somehow possible to do this? I prefet not to use abstract classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know you cant do it with decorator. But you can do that with creating an abstract base model class.

For example:

```
from django.db import models


class Site(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)


class AddSiteFkField(models.Model):
    fk_site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Test(AddSiteFkField):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```